# heroku undefined method `name' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

In my app it was User model without 'name' field, when I added this field by migration. On my localhost my sign up form works fine, but on heroku I have this log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<User:0x0000000518fb00>):
Rendered users/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.1ms)
     5:       = f.input :name, required: 'true'
     6:       = f.input :email, required: 'true'
     3:     %h1 Sign up
     4:     = simple_form_for @user do |f|
     7:       = f.input :password
     8:       = f.input :password_confirmation, required: 'true'
```

What I've tried:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:reset
```

but nothing helped.

Comment: can you post your migration and/or your db schema?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you also have to restart heroku after migrating - you'd want to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

Comment: cool could you mark as best answer? thanks! Glad to be of help.

Comment: I had tried heroku run rake db:migrate and didn't know what was going on. Just doing heroku restart solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have done `git add .`. Then `git status` to make sure that all the files have been committed. Then try the push again. Then migrate again.